# Is there a way to register Gmail account anonymously?

Tags: gmail, privacy

In days of old, you just entered login+pass+some dummy information, and you were done. Now, it asks for your mobile phone number, or your friend's phone number, or your home phone number.

Is there a way to create a Google account not bound to one's real life data?

Comment: Just because they ask for the data does not mean the data has to be real; use another service from Google such as Google Voice to get a number which you can use as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 3):

One easy way would be to use a disposable email address via [DisposeMail.com](http://disposeamail.com/) as the alternative email address Google registartion asks. That way you don't have to register to any other site, and you could even use the disposable address to recover your account just by writing down the address somewhere - no expiration.

Of course, it's better if the disposable address is nothing somebody else might use, for example an SHA1 hash of something. Like `0db939e32d0cc9a49f2660968676c8692b114713@disposeamal.com`

And if you want to be really, *really* anonymous you could use a bootable USB-stick for a separate, secure OS to protect from tracking methods like those used by [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/), and of course route all traffic thorugh [Tor](http://www.torproject.org/)... but I'm thinking you don't need quite that depth of anonymity. :)

Answer (score 2):

Google are asking for this information so that you can recover the account if you ever forget the password (for example).

So, if you are happy to have an account that you might not be able to access at some point in the future just enter garbage.

However, the extra information can be another non-Google e-mail address, so why don't you open up an account somewhere that doesn't ask for this information and use *that* for GMail.

Answer (score 1):

Today, in June 2017, the account creation process asks for a phone number, but it's not a required field.  I just left it blank.  I was able to create an account which had no connection to any other account and no connection to any real world identity.

Answer (score 0):

The more you do to avoid an audit trail on the account, the more likely it is that you'll look like a spammer to Gmail's spam detection systems.  Google does close Gmail accounts which are believed to belong to spammers.  So don't go too far in trying to avoid revealing any trace of an accountable identity to Gmail in account creation.